# How to fix the error observable in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to remove the current user that login thats why I used filter to.
but I get an error which is:

> Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Here's the code:

```
@Select(UserPageState.get('collection')) users$: Observable<Array<Partial<User>>>;
async ngOnInit() {
  const USER = this.creds.credentials['id'];
  this.users$.subscribe(param => param.filter(x => x.id !== USER));
  await this.store.dispatch(new UserPageList({ start: 1, length: this.pageSize })).toPromise();
}
```

***HTML***

```
<ag-grid-angular
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      [class]="(darkMode$ | async) ? 'ag-theme-balham-dark' : 'ag-theme-balham'"
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      [rowData]="users$ | async"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in below statement, subscribing to an observable returns an Subscription instance and you are again assigning it to observable.

```
this.users$ = this.users$.subscribe(param => param.filter(x => x.id !== USER));
```

Just don't assign it to observable again, it will resolve the issue.

```
this.users$.subscribe(param => param.filter(x => x.id !== USER));
```

Comment: But it didn't remove the user that I login.

Comment: You do not need to assign to users$ again. If you need Subscription instance then create some another variable. Why have you assigned it to users$ again ?

Comment: cause the value didn't pass to the observable

Comment: Still you do not need to assign it ti users$ again. please remove it and run your program again

Comment: still its not working. even I remove the ```this.users$ =```

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz instance ?